# Finding lat/lon of corners of geotiff file

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, latitude-longitude

I just recently managed to turn a GeoTIFF file into a .bmp file using gdal_translate.  Now I need to find the latitude/longitude coordinates of the corners.  I would prefer to use more of the gdal code or utilities, but that is not essential.  Does anyone have a good way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

```
gdalinfo [filename]
```

Will display a bunch of information about your geotiff including the corner coordinates

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try.  Wow, it worked perfectly!  My situation would be improved, though, if I could get that information into variables rather than into a file?  Is there a good way to do that.

Comment: @user1240592 That is going to have to be another question =) Probably not even for this SE, either SuperUser, Unix&Linux, or some other. It all depends on what scripting/programming language and OS you are using.

Comment: @ user1240592 - If David's answer is correct, you should select it as the right answer.  Not only does this reward him with points toward his overall reputation, doing this will also assist other people on the site in finding the answer to a similar question.  Other members of the community will also be more inclined to help you if you make a habit of selecting a correct answer.

Comment: David's answer is correct and I put in my comment because I don't know how to officially say that.  I just clicked the up arrow, but I see no definite way to do this.  If you would but tell me, I will do it.