# Getting geotiff information into variables, not files, using gdal_translate, gdalinfo

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, latitude-longitude

I received an excellent answer to [my question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21308/finding-lat-lon-of-corners-of-geotiff-file/21309#comment28877_21309) of how to get the lat/lon coordinates of the corners of a geotiff file.  I used gdalinfo.  The lat/lon info comes out into a file.  Similarly I turned the geotiff file into a bmp file using gdal_translate thanks to work colleague in another city who is hard to get hold of.  It would be much better for me if I could get the bmp file directly into memory, and the lat/lon coordinates directly into C++ variables.  Can anyone give me advice on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

you can check the source code of gdalinfo. try GDALGetGeoTransform